# Knockout does not seems to like the ! (exclamation point) before my function

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

I need to show/hide buttons depending on whether:

- (1) there are some pending changes
- (2) there is already a save in progress

I have `canSave` function for these 2 conditions.

My viewModel:

```
var canSave = ko.computed(function () {
    return hasChanges() && !isSaving();
});
```

Below is my html where I use this `canSave` function:

- to show the `Remove` button only if not `canSave`
- to show the `Save` button only if `canSave`
- to show the `Cancel` button only if `canSave`

My html:

```
<a data-bind="visible: !router.activeItem().canSave, 
              click: router.activeItem().deleteDocuments">
    Remove
</a>

<a data-bind="visible: router.activeItem().canSave, 
              click: router.activeItem().save">
    Save
</a>

<a data-bind="visible: router.activeItem().canSave, 
              click: router.activeItem().cancel">
    Cancel
</a>
```

It works pretty well for the `Save` & `Cancel` buttons **BUT it doesn't work for the `Remove` button: the button is never visible. It seems the `!` before the `canSave` function is the problem.**

PS: I need to show the `Remove` button only when there are no pending changes and no save is in progress. That's why I need to call `!router.activeItem().canSave`

---

UPDATE

Finally, I got it working by surrounding my html links with a `ko if` condition like this:

```
<!-- ko if: router.activeItem().canUpdate -->
    <a data-bind="visible: !router.activeItem().canSave(), 
                  click: router.activeItem().deleteDocuments">
        Remove
    </a>

    <a data-bind="visible: router.activeItem().canSave(), 
                  click: router.activeItem().save">
        Save
    </a>
    <a data-bind="visible: router.activeItem().canSave(), 
                  click: router.activeItem().cancel">
        Cancel
    </a>
<!-- /ko  -->
```

Please note I don't set parenthesis at the end of `ko if: router.activeItem().canUpdate`.

The advantage of this is when navigating on another (durandal) page if the target page don't have the `canUpdate` function it will not "go deeper of my html" and don't get an error on the expression `!router.activeItem().canSave()` which don't exists on the target page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should unwrap `canSave` computed when use it in expression:

```
<a data-bind="visible: !router.activeItem().canSave(), 
              click: router.activeItem().deleteDocuments">
    Remove
</a>
```

Comment: When I unwrap `canSave` as you suggest, it works for the Save, Cancel and Remove buttons. BUT for the Remove button: when I navigate to another page I got errors in the console: `Object doesn't support property or method 'canSave'`. I should say that I'm using Durandal (SPA template).

Comment: Maybe on another page activeItem doesn't have canSave computed. Where is it defined?

Comment: I updated my question to details wat I do. Thanks for your help.